# Running a command over several files and keep the same name

Tags: linux, macos, command-line-interface

How can I run a shell command on several files in linux/mac while keeping the same name (excluding the extension) ?

e.g. let's assume that I want to compile a list of files using a command to some other files with the same name :

```
{command} [name].less [same-name].css
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Supposing, more generally, that the two targets are located in two different paths, say, "path/to/folder2" and "path/to/folder3" and keeping in mind you can always specify the list used in the for cycle, you can try:

```
for i in $(ls path/to/folder3 | grep .less); do . /path/to/folder1/script.sh  $(echo "path/to/folder3/$i $( echo "path/to/folder2/$i" | sed -e s/.less/.css/)") ; done
```

Still sorry for the brutality and perhaps non-elegant solution.

Comment: Now, what if I have these files into two different directories ? So the `command` is actually a script in `folder1` , css files are in `folder2` and less files are in `folder3`  . How can we change this command somehow that it works like this ?

Comment: @arian-hosseinzadeh Does this meet your requests? Please could you check if i didn't made a mess with the paths numbers, with a dry run, like using the "echo" command as {command}?

Comment: Please note that the {} are just a way to recognise where the *command* is ran in the line. Remove them and retry, I'm editing my answer to avoid future misunderstanding. Ty for your reply.

Comment: @Hardon : I run this command : `for i in $(ls style | grep .less); do . node_modules/.bin/lessc $(echo 'style/$i $( echo 'public/stylesheets/$i' | sed -e s/.less/.css/)') ; done` and it returns this error : `-bash: node_modules/.bin/lessc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('` while when I run the same command only on one file: `node_modules/.bin/lessc style/* > public/stylesheets/style.css` , it doesn't return this error.

Comment: @Hardon : maybe you didn't consider `>` in the original command ?

Comment: @Arian Exactly, your original question was formulated without requiring any output redirection between two targets.
Otherwise you can still modify the above command this way:

    `for i in $(ls path/to/folder3 | grep .less); do ./path/to/folder1/executable  $(echo "path/to/folder3/$i > $( echo "path/to/folder2/$i" | sed -e s/.less/.css/)") ; done`

Comment: @Hardon: I run this command : `for i in $(ls style | grep .less); do . node_modules/.bin/lessc  $(echo "style/$i > $( echo "public/stylesheets/$i" | sed -e s/.less/.css/)"); done` and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ls sameName.*
```

or simply

```
ls same* > list_of_filenams_starting_with_SAME.txt
```

Comment: Maybe my post was misleading, by `same` , I didn't mean a prefix , I meant the same name as `name`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the more concise, performant and intuitive solution is to use `GNU Parallel`. Your command becomes:

```
parallel command {} {.}.css ::: *.less
```

So, for example, let's say your *"command"* is `ls -l`, and you have these files in your directory:

```
Freddy Frog.css     
Freddy Frog.less
a.css
a.less
```

then your command would be

```
parallel ls -l {} {.}.css ::: *.less

-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0  7 Aug 08:09 Freddy Frog.css
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0  7 Aug 08:09 Freddy Frog.less
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0  7 Aug 08:09 a.css
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  0  7 Aug 08:09 a.less
```

The benefits are firstly that it is a nice, concise syntax and a one-liner. Secondly, it'll run commands in parallel using as many cores as your CPU(s) have so it will be faster. If you do that, you may want the `-k` option to keep the outputs in order from the different commands.

If, you need it to run across many folders in a hierarchy, you can pipe the filenames in like this:

```
find <somepleace> -name \*.less | parallel <command> {} {.}.css
```

To understand these last two points (piping in and order), look at this example:

```
seq 1 10 | parallel echo
6
7
8
5
4
9
3
2
1
10
```

And now with `-k` to keep the order:

```
seq 1 10 | parallel -k echo
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If, for some reason, you want to run the jobs sequentially one after the other, just add the switch `-j 1` to the `parallel` command to set the number of parallel jobs to 1.

Try this out on your Linux machine as `GNU Parallel` is generally installed there. On the Mac under OS X , the easiest way to install `GNU Parallel` is with `homebrew` - please ask before trying if you are not familiar.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run this command , as it's part of a script which I want to run on Heroku and I cannot install `GNU parallel` I guess